# Нужно ли добавлять файлы миграции в git.igone?

Tags: laravel, laravel5

Вопрос такой. Как лучше всего работать с миграциями при переносе проекта на рабочий сервер? Вот у меня есть локальный проект, на котором есть миграции и я их выполнил к локальной бд. Нужны ли потом эти миграции у меня на рабочем сервере, если я выполню импорт моей бд в рабочую?

Comment: Да нужен на рабочем серверу, потому что может у Вас нужно будет создать еще таблицы или добавить к существом таблицу строка

Comment: Я имею ввиду, нужно ли при этом тащить на сервак старые файлы миграций? Если всё уже было сделано.

Comment: У вас и локально, и на сервере должен быть один и тот же набор миграций. Причём он должен быть такой, чтобы после удаления базы, вы по миграциям могли заново её создать. Поэтому никакие миграции не удаляйте, везде их синхронизируйте и применяйте